# Add text/link next to the last word of each post

Tags: posts, content

I'd like to add a custom message or a link next to the last word of all posts. Like this:

`This is any post of my wp blog. This is the last word of my post: last word. [text/link here]`

I've been using this filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {

if(is_single() && !is_home())
{
    $content .= '<a href="https://anylink.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Text</a>';
}
return $content; }, 99 );
```

However, the filter breaks the last line. It adds the custom link in a new paragraph below the last line of the posts or "the_content".

I'd need my custom link next to the last word of each and every published post.

Answer (score 0):

If your site or post type doesn't use Gutenberg, this is likely because of [the `wpautop` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/): it is applied with priority `10` on `the_content` filter, so the paragraph tags have already been added by the time your filter is running. Changing your callback's priority to be less than `10` will likely solve your issue.

If your site/CPT does use Gutenberg, then an HTML parser will be necessary to add in your link. See the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100692/get-last-li-element-from-a-string

Comment: Thanks for the answer Caleb :-) I changed the priority to 1,2... 9 but It didn't work  ;-(   <br/>I checked the html that my filter is returning and I noticed wp is automatically wrapping my added text/link with  <p></p> . This is what is causing the line break. Is there anyway I can prevent these tags from  being added?

Comment: You do not need to repeat your question.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry because I don't have the slightest idea of how to fit that in my filter.